# Installing Nimble for Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, buildconfig

I came across Nimble yesterday, but couldn't get past [Step 1](http://sites.google.com/site/nimbledoc/nimble-installation), configuring `BuildConfig.groovy` to find the Nimble's remote repository.

My `BuildConfig.groovy` file is one line:

```
grails.plugin.repos.discovery.intient="http://intient.com/downloads/grails/
```

Here is the message I get when running **grails install-plugin nimble 0.2**:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.1.1 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /opt/dev/sdks/grails-1.1.1

Base Directory: /home/wraith/dev/source/demo
Running script /opt/dev/sdks/grails-1.1.1/scripts/InstallPlugin.groovy
Environment set to development
No authentication for svn repo at intient ...
Reading remote plugin list ...
Reading remote plugin list ...
Reading remote plugin list ...
Plugin 'nimble' was not found in repository. If it is not stored in a configured repository you will need to install it manually. Type 'grails list-plugins' to find out what plugins are available.
```

This is the first time I have tried to install a plugin not in the official repository.  What is the best way to narrow down if it is a problem at Intient.com or with my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [these instructions](http://sites.google.com/site/nimbledoc/nimble-installation) with the following modifications:

- **Step 1 is correct**
- Instead of using the remote repository, [download the zipped plugin](http://github.com/intient/nimble/downloads)
- Move the plugin to *~/dev/plugins*
- *grails install-plugin ~/dev/plugins/grails-nimble-0.2.zip*
- **Steps 3-5 are correct**

Answer (score 2):

We were performing some maintenance on intient.com and the load balancer wasn't providing this content for the last 12 hours or so (oops!).

Should be sorted now but the steps Wraith Monster gave above work for a manual install as well.

Once Grails 1.2 proper hits Nimble will be part of the official plugin repo and we won't need to worry about this at all.

Comment: Thanks, Bradley. I tried Nimble with the app-engine plugin and could not get it to work. Any room on your roadmap for App Engine integration?

Comment: At this point I have no plans to work on this myself however if the community was wanting to get it to work I'd be happy to integrate it to core.

Answer (score 1):

you could always download the zip file for the plugin and install it manually

Comment: Do I replace the URL above with a local directory? Should the zip file be extracted?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download source code from http://github.com/intient/nimble
2. Unzip under your plugins directory of your project (usually under `${USER_HOME}/.grails/<grails-version>/projects/<myproject>/plugins`)
3. Rename the extracted folder into "nimble-0.2"
4. Remove from BuildConfig the line  `grails.plugin.repos.discovery.intient="http://intient.com/downloads/grails/"`
5. Edit the file application.properties of your project and add the line `plugins.nimble=0.2`
6. If not installed under your project, you should install the plugins : shiro (version 1.0-SNAPSHOT at least) and mail (>0.6). (run command `grails install-plugin <pluginName> <version>`)
7. Start directly from [Step 3](http://sites.google.com/site/nimbledoc/nimble-installation)

It should work (at least, it worked for me). Good luck